# How do I get the start and endpoint of a line using the middle point and the angle?

Tags: geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

I have a line that goes from P1 to P2 in a 2D space. I have the location of the middle point of that line, and the angle of inclination of the line. The thing is that I don't know the length of the line. Is it possible to find the location of the origin point?

Many Thanks!

Comment: no, you cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are many lines with the same inclination and the same middle point, so this is not a sufficient amount of information ; you need one more information to be able to compute the end points.

As an example, the segments between the points $(-x,0)$ and $(x,0)$ for $x > 0$ all have midpoint at $(0,0)$ and inclination of 0 degrees.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Ok, but if I had the length of the Line, what do I need to do to get the two points?

Comment: You need to post another question specifying the above requirements in one shot.

Comment: @CarlosT : If you have the length $L$ of the line, then the endpoints are at a distance $L/2$ in the direction of the inclination of the line. This becomes the computation of two vectors and adding coordinates. Do you need explanations for this?

Comment: No, got it, thanks!